# Trying to create dynamic widget area using post ID

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

In functions.php I added this code.

```
function page_widget_init( $post_id = 0 ) { {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Page Widgets', 'seven_theme' ),
        'id' => 'page-widgets-' . $post_id,
        'description' => __( 'To display Layers Widgets in front page, before your posts, after header.', 'seven_theme' ),
    ) );    
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'page_widget_init', 100 );
```

First how to get post id in functions.php register_sidebar **$post_id**

Now going to page template which i created using page.php, called Blog Template

Call this widget in this page.

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'page-widgets-' . $post->ID );
```

My idea is to create unique widget content using post ID.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: I trying my best to explain code and what i want, first code showing how to  create widget area, but but widget id will be dynamic according to post id. Second line showing how to call widget area in front end, but something using post ID, so that each page we create have same widget but different content.